# How to get media from Twilio incoming MMS that hits Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sms, twilio, mms

I have set up a Twilio number to post to my app's api controller. The controller is hit when I send a photo message to the Twilio number and the response text is sent properly which is nice. I am using the Twilio.Mvc and Twilio.TwiML nuget packages.

I'm wondering how I can get access to the image from the photo message in my controller. With the code below, `twilioRequest` always comes in as `null`. It is `null` regardless of if I send an SMS or MMS to my Twilio number.

Am I using TwilioRequest properly or is there some other parameter I can use to get information from the message in my controller? The messages are sending and being responded to properly, but I do not know how to view and use the content/media sent to my Twilio number.

```
    // POST: api/TestResponse
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(TwilioRequest twilioRequest)
    {
        var twilioResponse = new TwilioResponse();

        twilioResponse.Sms("This is a test response text");

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, twilioResponse.Element, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
     }
```

Thank you very much for your time. Please let me know if I am being unclear or if you need any additional information from me.

Answer (score 1):

The MMS parameters are directly in the Request object.  Here is the gist of what worked for my MVC project:

```
var tmp= Request.Params["NumMedia"];
int numMedia= int.Parse(tmp);
if(numMedia > 0)
{
    var msg = "Found " + numMedia + " mms things";

    for (int i = 0; i < numMedia; i++)
    {
        var mediaType = Request.Params["MediaContentType" + i];
        var mediaUrl = Request.Params["MediaUrl" + i];
        //save the info to the database or download the media
    }
    //do something with 'msg'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

I had a similar problem while working on this [project with OpenCV](http://twilioinc.wpengine.com/2015/11/getting-started-with-opencv-and-python-featuring-the-martian-2.html).

The example there is in Python as I haven't tried HTTP libraries for C#. But the mechanics are the same. Basically, if [Twilio's Request Parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) of `'NumMedia'` is not empty, then you can grab the content from the URL where Twilio stores media, `'MediaUrl{N}'`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. I expected `NumMedia` or `MediaUrl` to be attributes of `twilioRequest` when my api was hit, but `twilioRequest` is `null`. Does that sound reasonable or would you expect those values elsewhere? I don't know how to check `NumMedia` or `MediaUrl{N}`.